# DROP TRIGGER statement after RENAME TABLE statement in MySQL results in "Error Code: 1146. Table 'testschema.TestRenamed' doesn't exist"

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.7.10 and noticed that if a table that has an existing trigger is renamed via a RENAME TABLE statement, attempting to drop the existing trigger will result in a "Table doesn't exist" error. See the sample script below to demonstrate the error.

```
CREATE SCHEMA testschema DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;

USE testschema;

CREATE TABLE Test(
  id  int not null primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(255)
);

delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER TEST_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT ON Test
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   SET NEW.name = CONCAT(NEW.name, '_X');
END//
delimiter ;

RENAME TABLE Test TO TestRenamed;

DROP TRIGGER TEST_TRIGGER;
```

Executing the script above will give the following response:

`"Error Code: 1146. Table 'testschema.TestRenamed' doesn't exist"`

However executing the following query returns a row showing the table was successfully renamed.

`SELECT * from information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'testschema' AND TABLE_NAME = 'TestRenamed';`

What are the options, for dropping a trigger after renaming a table?

EDIT: I have filed a [bug report with MySQL](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79873) but would also like to hear if there is a potential workaround for dropping these triggers in the meantime.

EDIT 2: Just for more information about the environment, this is on OSX El Capitan 10.11.2 and the disk is case insensitive OSX Extended File System.

EDIT 3: This appears to be an OSX specific issue. I have verified the script works as desired on MySQL in Linux Mint.

Comment: Does the obvious workaround of "rename the table back to the original name, drop the trigger, rename again" not work?

Comment: Unfortunately, that approach seems to have the same problem. Here is a gist of a run trying that out. https://gist.github.com/qvaughan/10156ee10f6c82de7e3a

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem.

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.10    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> CREATE SCHEMA `testschema`
       DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> USE `testschema`;
Database changed

mysql> CREATE TABLE `Test` (
    ->   `id`  int not null primary key auto_increment,
    ->   `name` varchar(255)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,01 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `TEST_TRIGGER` BEFORE INSERT ON `Test`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->    SET NEW.`name` = CONCAT(NEW.`name`, '_X');
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> RENAME TABLE `Test` TO `TestRenamed`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> SHOW TRIGGERS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Trigger: TEST_TRIGGER
               Event: INSERT
               Table: TestRenamed
           Statement: BEGIN
                        SET NEW.`name` = CONCAT(NEW.`name`, '_X');
                      END
              Timing: BEFORE
             Created: **********
            sql_mode: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
             Definer: **********
character_set_client: utf8
collation_connection: utf8_general_ci
  Database Collation: utf8_general_ci
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> DROP TRIGGER `TEST_TRIGGER`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)
```

Please, show the result of executing the statement: `SHOW TRIGGERS\G`, before executing `DROP TRIGGER;`.

Comment: Thanks for looking, here is the tee output from my run with the SHOW TRIGGERS output: https://gist.github.com/qvaughan/ab4d107c7bd0de4ab852

Comment: Just for more information about the environment, this is on OSX El Capitan 10.11.2 and the disk is case insensitive OSX Extended File System.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the operating system and version you tested this against so I can update the bug report with MySQL?

Comment: @MichaelVaughan: Test using: Ubuntu 15.10 (32 bits).

Comment: Thanks for the info!